# ¿Las cookies pueden ser editadas al igual que el Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, aplicación-web, cookies, spa, refreshtoken

estoy tratando de aprender un poco sobre el uso del refresh token, y me llamo la atencion que se recomendaba que el refresh token se guardara en una cookie y el propio token en el local storage, pero no se si las spa pueden manejar las cookis como por ejemplo angular y react.

La persona me respondio que las cookies solo pueden borradas pero no editadas por eso es el lugar ideal para guardar un refresh token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Que son las cookies?

Las cookies son un pequeño archivo de texto plano que son creadas desde la pagina web que visitas y son almacenadas por tu navegador en tu máquina. Esto significa:

- El usuario puede modificar, manipular, borrar, etc... Las cookies ya que estas son almacenadas en su máquina en texto plano.
- No se debe basar la seguridad del sitio en las cookies, ya que estas pueden ser modificadas.
- Si se crea una cookie con algún tipo de información delicada se debe
  encriptar esta información de manera segura.

Puedes usar una cookie para almacenar un refresh token, pero no es para nada recomendable ya que es modificable por el usuario y mas si la información no esta debidamente protegida.

Comment: Entonces cual es el mejor lugar para almacenar un refresh token amigo? cual es la mejor practica y la mas segura?.

Comment: Buena pregunta, te dejo un articulo que explica la que yo considero la manera mas segura de manejar access tokens, https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/22/okta-authjs-pkce. Esta en ingles pero lo puedes ir traduciendo. Es para leerlo con calma, pero ya veras que te sirve mucho.